# Grease pencil gets all jittery once rendered

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

Basically, I've got a render of a room here:
[image]
However when I add my character the render shows grease pencil strokes all jittery
[image]
And the weird part is that the viewport looks completely fine.
I think that this is due my pc specs, however, I am not certain.

The render engine is Eevee